# Difference between HTML "overflow : auto" and "overflow : scroll"

Tags: html, css

When I was studying the `overflow` property's values, I came across these two values: `auto` and `scroll`, which adds scrollbar(s) if the content overflows the element.

Could someone please explain me whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Auto will only show a scrollbar when any content is clipped.

Scroll will however always show the scrollbar even if all content fits and you cant scroll it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a difference, on the latest version of Safari at least: Even with `scroll`, I don't see the scrollbar if the content fits. But, just to be safe, I went with `auto` because I only want to show a scrollbar when the content is clipped.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale OS X and Windows display scrollbars in different ways. You are probably using Safari on Mac right? OS X often hides the scrollbar until you actually scroll.

Comment: There seems to be more difference than that, `overlow: scroll` makes the box thinner: http://jsbin.com/letog/2/edit

Comment: In Safari 12 (probably earlier versions too), unless scroll bars are configured to show always, `overflow: scroll` and `overflow: auto` are functionally identical when the container is large enough to contain the content.

Comment: Same for Firefox, at least for Version 114.0.2, functionality seems to be identical with both.

Answer (score 27):

`overflow: scroll` will hide all overflowing content and cause scroll bars to appear on the element in question. If the content does not overflow, the scrollbars will still be visible, but disabled.

`overflow: auto` is very similar, but the scrollbars only appear when the content is overflowing.

There is a similar explanation of this [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/), with some screenshots to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/).

Auto will show scrollbar if and only if the content overflows; but scroll will always show the scrollbar, whether the content is overflowing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a point to the answer, `Overflow:auto` not worked in IE7 when position of the container is absolute [Position relative overflow IE7](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/). But setting `Overflow:scroll` works

Answer (score 0):

overflow: scroll will show both horizontal and vertical scrollbar even when you don't need one or other. while, overflow: auto will show the scrollbar which your div needs. so basically auto will help you to get rid of both scollbar.
Here is more of that:

https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, overflow: scroll will always show the scrollbar and overflow: auto will show the scrollbar only if the content is overflowing. In macOS, the overflow: scroll and overflow: auto will always show the scrollbar if the content is overflowing. Tested in Chrome. I highly recommend using overflow: auto as it works the same way and does not generate problems in windows

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to read all existing answers before providing your own, to ensure that you don't just repeat information that's already been provided.