# Autocomplete add scroll down after this many items jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Hi I am trying to create a scroll down for my autocomplete.  I want it to start scrolling down after 20 parts so it doesn't expand the page any bigger.

I have an example of my autocomplete function on this page here... Type 1 or 9 in one of the input boxes.

http://www.bivar.com/test.aspx

Does anyone know of a way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some simple CSS

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Change `400px` to whatever fits your needs.

Edit: For only vertical scrollbars:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Your awesome! How can i remove the left to right scroll bar? or is this not possible?

Comment: nvm you change it to auto instead of scroll

Comment: Does auto do the same thing as overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689412/difference-between-html-overflow-auto-and-overflow-scroll)